# Windows 7 Libraries, can I set the default view?

Tags: shell, windows-7, customization, libraries

I have added a custom library in Window 7 for our users to add all their custom data files.  We have a custom property handler and filter dll for searching and filtering and all that works great.

I would like to format our library's view to start in detail view with our custom columns showing for the first time the user goes to our library link in explorer or file open.  Does anyone know if this is possible and if it is supported?

I know that you can set the folderType for the library, is it possible to created a custom folder type for windows?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after no response and a couple days of work, I found one way to do this.  What I decided to do is write the registry entries for the current user that specifies the default view for the Generic Library.  Now this could cause issues for any other generic library as I am essentially setting my column types for all generic libraries.  Here are the keys you will need to write if you want to set these values for your generic library.

CurrentUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes{5F4EAB9A-6833-4F61-899D-31CF46979D49}

and

CurrentUser\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell{5F4EAB9A-6833-4F61-899D-31CF46979D49}

Hope someone else finds this useful as I think I am the only person trying to do this.